# Let $X$ be a Binomial Random Variable with parameters $n$ and $0<p<1$. Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} E(1+X)\cdot E\Big(\frac{1}{1+X}\Big)=1$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, binomial-distribution

**Question :** Let $X$ be a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $0<p<1$.

- Find $\mathbb{E}\Big(\frac{1}{1+X}\Big)$
- Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}(1+X)\cdot \mathbb{E}\Big(\frac{1}{1+X}\Big)=1$

**My Attempt :** I have already computed $\mathbb{E}\Big(\frac{1}{1+X}\Big)$. But while solving another part, I reached here:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\bigg((np+1)\cdot\frac{(1-(1-p)^n+1)}{(n+1)p}\bigg)$$

I got confused. What steps should I take to compute the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should have something that looks like this:
$$
\lim_{n \to\infty} (1 + np)\cdot\left(1 - (1-p)^{n+1} \over (n+1)p \right).
$$

When we distribute all of this through we will end up with:

$$
\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(1 - (1-p)^{n+1} \over (n+1)p \right) + \lim_{n \to\infty} \left(np - np(1-p)^{n+1} \over (n+1)p \right).
$$

In the first equation, the numerator will never exceed $2$ because $(1-p)^{n+1}$ is going to be less than $1$ because we know that $0 \lt p \lt 1.$ but the denominator is going to blow up to $\infty$, making the first term completely $0$.

On the term on the right, I find it easiest to artfully multiply by 1, by dividing both the numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{n}$, but taking L'Hopital's would also work. Observe:

$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}[np - np(1-p)^{n+1}] \over \frac{1}{n}[(n+1)p] \right) = \left( p - p(1-p)^{n+1} \over p + \frac{p}{n} \right).
$$

Under the limit the $p(1-p)^{n+1}$ is going to go to zero, as well as the $\frac{p}{n}$, and you will be left with $\frac{p}{p}$ which equals $1$ as desired.